# Does Share have any side effect?

Tags: memory

According to the documentation,

> `Share[expr]` changes the way `expr` is stored internally, to try and minimize the amount of memory used.

How should I then interpret the fact that `x1 != x2 + x3` after running the following code?

```
e = Table[j (x + i), {i, 5}, {j, i}];
x1 = ByteCount@e
x2 = Share[e]
x3 = ByteCount@e
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I give it a try to answer your question.

The way `Share` works is, that all symbols in the symbol table are checked, and those with the same values are cross-referenced. So you can not expect that your `e` is reduced but if there is another `e` (say `e2`) with exact the same value, it will get cross referenced.

Let's check this assumption. The Integral of `x^66 Sin[x]^44` takes about ~500MB:

```
ByteCount[tmp1 = Integrate[x^35 Sin[x]^44, x]]
=> 506960
```

To get the size of the *Mathematica* subexpression we can use `LeafCount`:

```
LeafCount[tmp2 = Integrate[x^35 Sin[x]^44, x]]
=> 13076
```

Now `tmp1` and `tmp2` do have exactly the same value. Let's check the memory in use:

```
MemoryInUse[]
=> 52558032
```

If we call now `Share` there should be a considerable amount of reduced memory consumption:

```
Share[]
=> 9857528

MemoryInUse[]
42921264
```

If we subtract these values, we may expect that we see the reduction of (`tmp1 + tmp2`) into one `tmp` for instance. The problem is we don't since `MemoryInUse[]` does involve state changes and so it is nearly impossible to get a discrete state.

If we try to call `Share` on `tmp2` we will realise, that `Share` is not able to save any memory for `tmp2`, since it is already cross-referenced with `tmp1`.

This is how `Share[]` basically works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand what you wrote, what bothers me is the statement in the documentation "Share returns the number of bytes freed as a result of sharing …" `x2` of the original question is not zero, so where did those savings go?